# Can I scrape an HTML class without using a 3rd party library like HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I wanted to make a program which reads the description of a picture album over at imgur.com (this for example: https://imgur.com/gallery/DsAE9cv)

The element would be

```
<div class="post-image-description">One owner?</div>
```

but I have a hard time getting the description (One owner).

Would be very helpful to get some tips!

I tried using HtmlAgilityPack and using the XPath, but it's not working.

```
string link = txt_Link.Text;

var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(link);

var description = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html[1]/body[1]/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]");

txt_Return.Text = description.ToString();
```

I expected the output of "One owner?" but I got "NULL" (textbox is showing "HtmlAgility.Node".

Comment: I think you just need to add `/text()` to the end of your xpath. You've got the node but not the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`description.ToString()` does not return the expected result.

Use `description.InnerText` property to view the title.

Returns "One owner?" in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some online XPath tester tool, like http://xpather.com/

You might try this XPath to get the result you need:

```
//p[@class='post-image-description']/text()
```